# UITableView/UIScrollView scrollToItemAtIndex

Tags: iphone, uiscrollviewdelegate

I'm trying to call

```
[tableView scrollToItemAtIndex: [tableView indexForCell: firstVisibleCell] atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

To force my table to 'snap' to the first visible item. This works fine, but I only get a call to

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

When scrolling had to be completed (which is stated in the document). Is there anyway that I can get the offset of the *firstVisibleCell* so I can do a comparison to see if scrolling is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexForCell:firstVisibleCell];
CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```